# Is Promise.all([]) equivalent to promise.then().then()

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Is this code

```
Promise.all([
  promise1,
  promise2,
])
.then(() => doSomething())
```

equivalent to

```
promise1
    .then(() => promise2)
    .then(() => doSomething())
```

I thought they were equivalent, but they do not behave the same on an fortunejs and mocha application. Below are more details about this application

---

I'm using [fortune.js](http://fortune.js.org/api/#fortune-delete) and I would like to write some tests using mocha. What I'm trying to achieve is to use the `beforeEach` hook to truncate tables in the database and then insert some predifined values. So if I have two tables called `customer` and `user` I will do something like this

```
beforeEach(function () {
  return Promise.all([store.delete('user'), store.delete('customer')])
    .then(() => store.create('customer', {
      id: '0987654321234567890',
      // More data
    }))
    .then(() => store.create('user', {
      id: 'qwertyuioppoiuytrewq',
      customer: '0987654321234567890',
      // More data
    }));
});
```

This code is not stable and works sometimes and sometimes not without I can find why (around 50% success rate)

But if I switch to this code it is working :

```
beforeEach(function () {
  return store.delete('customer')
  .then(() => store.delete('user'))
  .then(() => store.create('customer', {
     id: '0987654321234567890',
     // More data
  }))
  .then(() => store.create('user', {
     id: 'qwertyuioppoiuytrewq',
     customer: '0987654321234567890',
     // More data
   }));
});
```

I thought that

```
Promise.all([
  promise1,
  promise2,
])
.then(() => doSomething())
```

was equivalent to

```
  promise1
    .then(() => promise2)
    .then(() => doSomething())
```

Since [store.delete](http://fortune.js.org/api/#fortune-delete) returns a Promise, why do I have a different behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
Promise.all([
  promise1,
  promise2,
])
.then(() => doSomething())
```

starts to execute both promises at the same time and calls then() when the latest finished, while this

```
promise1
    .then(() => promise2)
    .then(() => doSomething())
```

starts with the first promise and when that's finished executes the second, and so forth.

Comment: Brillant ! The order is not the problem, but the problem is that I try to access the database twice at the same time

Comment: That's what all() is designed for. You can use each() or map() and others to resolve promises in order.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will do it ;)

Answer (score 1):

No they are not equivalent.

[The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for `Promise.all()` state that, though the return value is the order of the input promises, they are not resolved in that order.

Chaining promises with `.then()` resolves each promise in order.

Comment: The order is not a problem. The problem remains the same if I switch the order. The problem is that `Promise.all` execute promise at the time which is a problem for database access (see @marekful answer)

Comment: Our answers are the same. The order of _resolution_ is the problem.